# New User Login Creation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a user and login by using this script:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [Test_7] WITH PASSWORD=N'password1#', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON
GO

USE [ACMS]
GO

CREATE USER [Test_7] FOR LOGIN [Test_7]
GO

USE ACMS;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO Test_7;
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO Test_7
GRANT CREATE FUNCTION TO Test_7
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO Test_7

GRANT SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, ALTER, INSERT, EXECUTE-- , etc.
    ON SCHEMA::dbo
    TO Test_7
GO
```

When I connected to SQL Server using the new login and expand the folder `Security\Logins`, I see the two users `sa` and `Test_7`.

[image]

Is there any method to show only `Test_7` under the folder `Security\Logins` when I am connected to SQL Server using the login user `Test_7`?

Comment: Logins are created on the **server** level - they are not dependent on a specific login or anything - you will always see all the logins. There's no option to turn that off....

Comment: Sure, right-click on the SSMS Object explorer Logins node and add filter name equals Test_7.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a login and it has on `public` Server level role, then it will only see `sa` and not other logins.

Below is the configuration of the user on the server:

1. The General Configuration for the user:

[image]

2. The Server Role Mapping configuration for the user:

[image]

And you can see that if I connect with the user on the server, the I can only see the `sa` user and not others.

[image]

And trust me, I have other users on my server. Below is how the `Logins` folder looks if I connect with the `sa` user on the server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question. you want only showing your current login under security\logins. but this is impossible. 
And I don't how it will influence you if sa is there..

Answer (score 0):

There are options to hide Databases and other related information, but the one that you are asking is not possible.

The closest solution would probably be to Create Login only when you access and delete login details after use.